# Adding ALIAS to GIT config for a set of commands

Tags: git, config, alias

I have a problem adding an alias to my git config for this set of commands.

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

I tried this:

```
git config --global alias.rmd "ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm"
```

When I run `git rmd` this would prompt me with a missing parameter for ls-files.
**Is the alias syntax incorrect or perhaps there is a typo somewhere ... ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe is messing up the alias. You can do what you want by adding `!git` to the beginning of your alias.

Try:

```
git config --global alias.rmd '!git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm'
```

Note that I replaced your `"` quotes with `'` to stop the `!` from being expanded.

In your git config, you should now have the following:

```
[alias]
    rmd = !git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

Technically, `!` means "run in the shell as-is", so you that's why you need to add `git` at the beginning of your command line. The cool thing about `!` is you can start an alias with something other than git if you like.